# border overlaps text above link

Tags: html, css

HTML - snippet

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bot-text">
        <!-- <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer'); ?> -->
        <h1>Titley Title</h1>
        <p> paragraph of text ...</p>

        <a href="...">button text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bot-text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 80px;
  text-align: center;
}   

.bot-text p {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', serif;
  font-weight: 600; 
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}

.bot-text a {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

A title and paragraph of text created with a link created underneath. I have a border on the link with padding, the border overlays the text above.

How can I avoid this? I want the border to push the link down, not overlap the text above

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/jqaneuob/

Comment: @Dmitriy Please add that as an answer so it can be accepted. Basically it's because it needs to be a block level element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `<a>` elements a inline, you need it to be a `block` or `inline-block` level so it *"takes up space"* and does not go over elements. Making it `inline-block` would work the best here since we want some inline properties:

```
.bot-text a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  // <-- Add This
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

This was also noted in **@Dmitriy** comment.

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-bottom: 10px;` to the paragraph text

Comment: That's not going to work if the padding is changed on the `.bot-text a` element. Also this isn't really archiving the real desired affect.

Comment: Right, so then you just adjust the padding on the `p` element accordingly. They both achieve the desired affect IMO as the poster asked how to avoid the border from touching the text above - task accomplished.